Unirest not giving Reponse body for a GET API call
I am trying to do an API call using Unirest in java. I have a GET API call with me which has Authorization Bearer token as its header parameter. I am getting the status code as 200 , but an empty response Body. The API is designed to give me a JSON response. The Curl for the same API call is giving me the response body , but Unirest is not giving me the response.
This is my code
    String url = protocol + "://" + host + ":" + port + "/xbrl-mapper-service/services/xbrl-    api/v1/status?token=" + token;
    logger.log(Level.ALL, "Generated url for checking status: " + url);

    HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.get(url)
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token)
        .header("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
        .header("Pragma", "no-cache")
        .header("Expires", "0")
        .header("Accept", "application/json")
        .asString();
    
   String responseBody = response.getBody();

int statusCode = response.getStatus();
   logger.log(Level.ALL, "Response of checkStatus Method==>" +responseBody);
   logger.log(Level.ALL, "HTTP Status Code====> " + statusCode);


The log file output
Response of checkStatus Method==>
HTTP Status Code====> 200
As you can see Response is empty , i have verified the URL that is generated and the token that is being used as header parameter. The same url with header when done through curl command is giving me the repsonse body(JSON response)

What parameters do you use to make a curl request?

I am passing a header parameter(authentication token).
